# Не срабатывающий popstate и beforeunload

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование, встроенная-реклама

Необходимо поставить скрипт камбекера, чтобы **при нажатии на кнопку назад или закрыть окно**, всплывало окошко с текстом по типу "Подождите! Для вас есть уникальное предложение - скидка 50%".
Пример скрипта есть в данной статье: [https://yellowweb.top/скрипт-comebacker/](https://yellowweb.top/%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82-comebacker/).

Я наверстал следующую страницу с использованием камбекера.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.close-over, .close-undermodal').on('click', function() {
    $('#comebacker').fadeOut(300); // 300 скорость исчезновения | disappear speed
    $('body').removeClass('comebackerhidden');
  });

  var comebacker = true;

  /**
        $(window).mouseout(function(e){
            if(e.pageY - $(window).scrollTop() < 1 && comebacker == true){
                $('#comebacker').fadeIn(300); 
                $('body').addClass('comebackerhidden');
                comebacker = false;
            }
        });
    **/

  $(window).on('popstate', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(comebacker==true) {
       $('#comebacker').fadeIn(300);
       $('body').addClass('comebackerhidden');
       comebacker = false;
    }
  });

  $(window).on('beforeunload', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(comebacker==true) {
       $('#comebacker').fadeIn(300);
       $('body').addClass('comebackerhidden');
       comebacker = false;
    }
  });

  try {
    setTimeout(
      function show_comebacker() {
        $('#comebacker').fadeIn(300); // 300 скорость появления | appear speed 
        $('body').addClass('comebackerhidden');
      }, 3000 //Время появления в милисекундах | Appear time in milliseconds
    )
  } catch (e) {}
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700&subset=cyrillic-ext,latin-ext);

/* modal */

#comebacker {
  background: url(img/bgexit.png);
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  display: none;
}

#comebacker .close-undermodal {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#comebacker .close-over {
  background: url(img/close.png) no-repeat 0 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#comebacker .close-over:hover {
  background-position: 0 bottom;
}

#comebacker .over-window {
  background: url(img/product.png) no-repeat 40px center #fff;
  cursor: default;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 10%;
  margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 60px 20px 60px 20px;
  width: 560px;
  z-index: 9999;
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', arial, sans-serif !important;
}

#comebacker .title-comebacker {
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 0 30px 0;
  margin: 0 0 0 50%;
}

#comebacker .title-oui div {
  font-size: 20px;
}

#comebacker .form {
  margin: 0 0 0 50%;
}

#comebacker .form form {
  margin: 0 !important;
}

#comebacker .form input[type="text"] {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #a5a5a5;
  outline: none;
  height: 45px;
  line-height: 45px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', arial, sans-serif;
  width: 250px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 20px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
}

#comebacker .form input[type="text"]:focus {
  border: 1px solid #054155;
}

#comebacker .form input[type="submit"] {
  background: #054155;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  outline: none;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', arial, sans-serif;
  width: 250px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  border: 0px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

#comebacker .form input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background: #10a9dc;
}

.comebackerhidden {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Comebacker</title>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="comebacker/css.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="comebacker/script.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery-3.6.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="comebacker">
    <div class="close-undermodal"></div>
    <div class="over-window">
      <div class="close-over"></div>
      <div class="title-comebacker">
        <div>Order today!</div>
        Only: 15 $.
        <div>50% discount</div>
      </div>
      <div class="form">
        <form method="post" action="">
          <input type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="Name" />
          <input type="text" name="phone" value="" placeholder="Phone" />
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Order" />
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

В результате после закрытия файла `main.html` окно камбекера не возникает. Подскажите как добиться возникновения окна камбекера.
Привожу структуру проекта

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А в чем смысл вставки модального окна на `popstate` и `beforeunload`? Окно не возникает скорее всего так как сами элементы на которые Вы вешаете события не существуют в этот момент, тем более что скрипт с попапом Вы подключаете после того, как по-факту вешаете события на элемент `#comebacker`. Просто вставили бы Вашу модалку в html по-нормальному, такой проблемы не было бы. В `setTimeout()` не нужно именовать функцию, она может быть анонимной, так как у Вас конечно сработает, но обычно туда или передают или имя функции или анонимную функцию.

Comment: Так же `popWindow` ничего не возвращает. Вы или добавьте `return` или замените `() => {}` на `() => ()`

Comment: @Simon окно должно появляться после нажатия на кнопки Назад или закрытия окна, поэтому я использую события popState и beforeunload.

Comment: @Simon я вас не понял. Можете написать в виде кода как должно быть правильно по вашему?

Comment: Так у Вас не окно появляется, а Вы просто вставляете, вернее пытаетесь вставить HTML этого окна в документ на это событие., так как функция не возвращает HTML в том виде в котором Вы ее написали.

Comment: @Simon я что-то туплю, а как должно быть? Как создать окно камбекера?

Comment: Да просто в html его добавьте как в примере на который Вы [ссылаетесь](https://github.com/dvygolov/landingscripts/blob/master/index.html)

Comment: @Simon а кк добиться того, чтобы окно камбекера возникало после нажатия на кнопку Назад или 
 после закрытия окна?

Comment: Ну Вы же сами говорите что для этого используете `popstate`. Попробуйтк заменить `mouseout` который Вы используете сейчас для показа этого окна. Ну и убрать `e.pageY - $(window).scrollTop()` и что у Вас там еще в условии. Правда Вам придется немного поискать, каким образом Вам можно будет предотвратить дефолтное поведение для этого ивента, так как согласно докам это не сancelable ивент.

Comment: @Simon а дефолтное поведение для ивента popstate и beforeunload нельзя предотвратить с помошью   `e.preventDefault();`? Если нет, то как?

Comment: @Simon помогите очень надо. Я обновил вопрос.

Comment: Для этого наверное следовало бы создать отдельный вопрос, предыдущий заключался не в этом и мы не можем постоянно беседовать в комментариях. Ответы на эти вопросы уже есть в интернете [Is it possible to e.preventDefault in window.onPopState?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32432296/is-it-possible-to-e-preventdefault-in-window-onpopstate), `beforeunload` срабатывает не по закрытию а перед перезагрузкой окна.

Comment: @Simon а какое событие срабатывает по закрытию окна?

Comment: На сколько я знаю, на данный момент предотвращение закрытия вкладки ограничено со стороны браузеров, так как разработчики этим могли злоупотреблять. Раньше можно было использовать различным способом ивенты unload, beforeunload, но их функционал был ограничен. У Вас изначально в примере было `$(window).mouseover`, что предполагало что пользователь потянулся к панели браузера для определенного действия.

Comment: @Simon подскажите как быть на https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1450600/Отмена-дефолтного-поведения-события-popstate?