# Эффект всплывания окна

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, всплывающее-окно

Есть окно

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Comebacker</title>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="comebacker/css.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">
    < /script <
    script type = "text/javascript"
    src = "comebacker/script.js" >
  </script>
  <!--<script src="jquery-3.6.1.min.js"></script>-->
  <!--<script src="myPopupWindow.js"></script>-->
</head>

<body>
  TestContent
  <div id="comebacker">
    <div class="close-undermodal"></div>
    <div class="over-window">
      <div class="close-over"></div>
      <div class="title-comebacker">
        <div>Order today!</div>
        Only: 15 $.
        <div>50% discount</div>
      </div>
      <div class="form">
        <form method="post" action="">
          <input type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="Name" />
          <input type="text" name="phone" value="" placeholder="Phone" />
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Order" />
        </form>
      </div>
      <!--<div class="clear"></div>-->
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Есть css стиль для этого окна

```css
/* modal */
#comebacker {
    background: url(img/bgexit.png);
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0; 
    z-index: 9999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; 
    overflow: auto;
    display: none;
}
```

Для появления окна `#comebacker` необходимо изменить свойство `display: none` на `display: block`. Но мне нужно добиться эффекта всплывания окна. Каким образом в js (и jquery) это можно сделать (исключая `fadeIn` и `fadeOut`)? Возможно использование свойства opacity или каких-то других свойств. (как присвоить свойству opacity - 1 в js/jquery, если есть какие-то другие способы пишите)

P.S. А как сделать так, чтобы всплывающее (popup) окно возникало при клике на кнопку Назад или при закрытии вкладки (см. ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1450549/…)? Т.е. окно popup должно возникать внутри обработчиков событий $(window).on('popstate', ...) и $(window).on('beforeunload', ...). Проблема c e.preventDefault(), невозможно предотвратить действия по умолчанию, т.е. чтобы вместо перехода на предыдущую страницу или закрытия вкладки возникало всплывающее окно.

Answer (score 1):

Критикуешь - предлагай, как говорится, вот моё решение вашего вопроса, контент попапа уже на ваше усмотрение. Также заменил высоту попапа с `100%` (вся ширина родительского блока) на `100vh` (это вся высота экрана пользователя).

```js
let popup = document.querySelector('#comebacker')

document.querySelector('#open-popup').addEventListener('click', () => {
  popup.style.cssText = `
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;`
  setTimeout(() => {
    popup.style.opacity = '1'
  }, 1)
})

window.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if(e.explicitOriginalTarget === popup) {
  popup.style.opacity = 0
  setTimeout(() => {
    popup.style.display = 'none'
  }, 301)
  }
})
```

```css
#comebacker {
    background: url(img/bgexit.png) rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0; 
    z-index: 9999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh; 
    display: none;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    transition: .3s;
}
```

```html
<span id="open-popup">Click At Me!</span>

<div id="comebacker">
<span>Some Content Here</span>
</div>
```

К слову если вам нужно расположить контент поапа в центре то просто используйте вот такие вот стили:

```css
#comebacker {
  display: grid; /* Или flex */
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: @NNL993 а как сделать, чтобы всплывающее (popup) окно возникало при клике на кнопку Назад или при закрытии вкладки (см. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1450549/Не-срабатывающий-popstate-и-beforeunload)? Т.е. окно popup должно возникать внутри обработчиков событий $(window).on('popstate', ...) и $(window).on('beforeunload', ...). Проблема c e.preventDefault(), невозможно предотвратить действия по умолчанию.

Comment: Сохраните функции появления и исчезания попапа в отдельные переменные, и вызывайте их по пере необходимости. `const openPopup = () => { ... }; $(window).on('popstate', openPopup); // и так далее`

Comment: @vladwebsearch кстати, не думаю что событие `beforeunload` полезно для вас, т.к. функция выполнится, когда пользователь закроет окно, то есть он не увидит попап, другое дело если вкладка теряет фокус... `$(window).on('blur', openPopup);`.

Comment: @NNL993 см. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1451185/Предотвращение-дефолтного-поведения-событий-popstate-и-beforeunload-Использован - пишите там

Answer (score -1):

Как-то так попробуй, замени opacity на свои эффекты, так должен и block сработать и плавность эффектов.

```
let yourElem = document.getElementById('comebacker');
yourElem.style.display = 'block';
setTimeout(()=>{
   yourElem.style.opacity = '1';
}, 10)
```

Comment: Пишет: `Uncaught ReferenceError: yourElem is not defined`.

Comment: в yourElem тебе нужно поместить твой элемент типа -  yourElem = document.getElementById('comebacker'), я тебе не готовое решение под твои нужды написал, а основу того как сохранить плавные эффекты и переключить display c none на block

Comment: дополнил свой пример кода ^^

Comment: Во-первых, я не тс, во-вторых, а зачем тогда писать ответ если это не решение вопроса? И вы даже не сделали переключение обратно... Плюс к тому у вас некорректно подсвечивается код, но это уже придирки...

Comment: если я правильно понял, у человека не срабатывают эффекты плавности из-за того что они применяются в один момент с display block, когда у меня была такая проблема я ее решил через setTimeout, чтобы сперва сработал display block, а потом остальные эффекты, дальше подразумевается что человек подгонит это решение под свой случай

Comment: @ΝNL993, ну если так разжевывать, то люди думать своей головой разучатся

Comment: Я тоже считаю что человек должен подгонять ответ под себя, но у вас нет реализации скрытия попапа (плавной), в этом собственно и заключалась моя основная претензия, к тому же ваш ответ нельзя в лоб проверить (через сниппет). А насчёт "головой разучатся думать", я не согласен, я лично сам когда начинал учить JS, не мог ничего нормально писать и только по полным примерам других участников и документации я начинал понимать устройства JS-а.